# trying to get data between quarter and year range

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

[image: trying to get data between Q1 2015 and Q3 2019]

Hello All, I am trying to get data from Q1 2015 to Q3 2019 using following query in cakephp

```
$this->QuarterwiseData->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('QuarterwiseData.year BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($year_from, $year_to),
                'QuarterwiseData.quarter BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($quarter_from, $quarter_to))));
```

but it does not return expected result...

here is quarterwise_data table

[image]

my expected result is

[image]

and it returns below result-

[image]

*missing quarter 4 2015

Comment: I had a similar problem once, you can try this "workaround": multiply year by 10, add the quarter to it and then get between beginning-year*10 + beginning-quarter and end-year*10 + end-quarter. like BETWEEN 2015**1** AND 2019**3** bold representing the quarter

Comment: are you sure is cake3?

Comment: Hello, This process works for me ...SELECT * FROM quarterwise_data WHERE (quarterwise_data.year*10+quarterwise_data.quarter >= $year_from*10+$quarter_from) 
AND (quarterwise_data.year*10+quarterwise_data.quarter <= $year_to*10+$quarter_to)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know cakephp but in mysql here is what you want to do :

```
SELECT * FROM QuarterwiseData
WHERE (year > ?y1 and quarter > ?q1 ) AND ( year < ?y2 and quarter < ?q2)
```

So you can't use between here !

If I try to reuse your query it will be :

```
$this->QuarterwiseData->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('QuarterwiseData.year >? AND QuarterwiseData.quarter > ?'=>array($year_from, $quarter_from),
                'QuarterwiseData.year < ? AND QuarterwiseData.quarter < ?''=>array($year_to, $quarter_to))));
```